# What does multiplying a matrix A by B and B transpose mean?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

$$BA^TB^T$$

$A$ is ($m\times m$) while $B$ is ($n\times m$). In matlab this is written as: B*(A\B').

I don't understand what it means for $A$. What kind of transformation does it do on $A$? What does the result of this represent?

edit:

I've been asked to explain what I mean but what I am asking myself is what the result an expression like this yields. In a linear system

```
 Ax = b
```

I understand what  x= inverse(A)*b means. It solves the system. But if A and B are both matrices and not vectors what does it do?
And when that solution is again multiplied by the matrix b to form
     $$BA^TB^T$$
what does that expression mean? What is the transformation it effects.
I've explained my question as best as I could, I think you understand what I'm asking.
I'd very much like to read your answers.

edit #2:
For the original expression, I will provide some context as to where I have encountered it. It is used in a FETI-DP method and A is the original matrix reordered per domain and B is a matrix of connections of interface nodes in different domains. I hope this helps make it clearer.

Comment: Is $B$ orthogonal?

Comment: No, it's not orthogonal.

Comment: Nice job editing!

Comment: Thanks! I suppose that even if it seems straightforward a lot of people find it hard to understand it - hence no answers!

Comment: @Antoine if B was orthogonal could you give me an answer?

Comment: @System My question was stupid. $B$ cannot be orthogonal, because it is not even square matrix:) If it was square and orthogonal, then $BA^T B^T$ would be the same linear mapping as $A^T$ but in different basis.

Comment: "But if A and B are both matrices and not vectors what does it do?" Let $A^{-1}$ be inverse of $A$. $Ax = b$ is an equation and we try to find its solution $x$. As you have written, the solution is $A^{-1}b$. If $b = B$ is a matrix, then $X$ is also a matrix, but again, you can check that $X= A^{-1}B$ is a solution of $AX = B$, since $A(A^{-1}B) = (AA^{-1})B = B$. However, I do not understand the connection between this $Ax= b$ question and the title question.

Comment: In regards to your first comment, suppose B was square and orthogonal. Can you elaborate a bit about "then it would be the same linear mapping but in different basis." ? As for the second comment, let me explain as best as I can what I mean. x which is a vector and the solution to Ax=b I can envision as a system of linear equations where x is vector of the solutions. But when X is a matrix and the solution to AX=B I don't understand what exactly it is a solution to.

Comment: @Antoine I've also added a clarification to my question about the original expression and where I've encountered it.

Comment: Same mapping, different basis: [this video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate_bases/change_of_basis/v/linear-algebra-coordinates-with-respect-to-a-basis) seems promissing. Solving $AX = B$. If you can visualize $Ax = b$, all you have to note is that solving $AX = B$, where $B$ and $X$ have $d$ columns, is solving $d$ linear systems at once (write $X$ and $B$ as $d$ columns of unknowns/coefficients $x_i$/$b_i$ and  then note that in this case $Ax_i$ must equal $b_i$). I have no idea, what is FETI-DP method.